# Google Maps Data Driven Styling, styling not loaded on the map when using vue3

Tags: google-maps, vuejs3

I'm trying to make [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dds-boundaries/choropleth-map) work on my vue3 project but came to a very weird issue.

The same code works fine on vue2 but not on vue3 and there is no error shown, has anyone tried to use Google Data Driven Maps styling and figure out a way to use them in vue3?

Vue 3 Map(the map is loaded, but there is no data-driven styling included, no errors provided in console).: https://jsfiddle.net/dgalic/2pebj6ct/4/

```js
 const { createApp } = Vue

  createApp({
    name: 'MapStyling',
  data: function() {
    return {
      no_data: [null, "", undefined, "null"],
      mapName: "route-manager-map",
      bounds: {},
      map: {},
      markers: {},
      polylines: {},
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.defineMap()
  },
  methods: {
    defineMap() {
        /* eslint-disable */
      // this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      const element = document.getElementById(this.mapName);
      const options = {
        center: { lat: 30.266666, lng: -97.733330 },
        zoom: 12,
        mapId: "map_id",
      };
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(element, options);

      const featureLayer = this.map.getFeatureLayer(
        google.maps.FeatureType.POSTAL_CODE
      )

      
      featureLayer.style = function (placeFeature) {
        let fillColor = "blue";
        if (postal_codes.includes(placeFeature.feature.displayName)) {
          return {
            fillColor,
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
          }
        } else {
          return {
            fillColor,
            fillOpacity: 0
          }
        }
      }

      const postal_codes = [
        '78701',
        '78702',
        '78703',
        '78704',
        '78705'
      ]
    }
  }
  }).mount('#app')
```

```css
.google-map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #e5e3df;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API-KEY&libraries=places&v=beta"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div
       class="google-map"
       :id="mapName"
       ></div>
</div>
```

Vue 2 Map(works fine, same code): https://jsfiddle.net/dgalic/1wutoja2/8/

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  name: 'MapStyling',
  data: function() {
    return {
      no_data: [null, "", undefined, "null"],
      mapName: "route-manager-map",
      bounds: {},
      map: {},
      markers: {},
      polylines: {},
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.defineMap()
  },
  methods: {
    defineMap() {
      /* eslint-disable */
      // this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      const element = document.getElementById(this.mapName);
      const options = {
        center: {
          lat: 30.266666,
          lng: -97.733330
        },
        zoom: 12,
        mapId: "map_id",
      };
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(element, options);

      const featureLayer = this.map.getFeatureLayer(
        google.maps.FeatureType.POSTAL_CODE
      )


      featureLayer.style = function(placeFeature) {
        let fillColor = "blue";
        if (postal_codes.includes(placeFeature.feature.displayName)) {
          return {
            fillColor,
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
          }
        } else {
          return {
            fillColor,
            fillOpacity: 0
          }
        }
      }

      //   featureLayer = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(featureLayer))
      console.log(featureLayer.h.get('mapId'))

      const postal_codes = [
        '78701',
        '78702',
        '78703',
        '78704',
        '78705'
      ]
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
.google-map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #e5e3df;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API-KEY&libraries=places&v=beta"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="google-map" :id="mapName"></div>
</div>
```

Any help or feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue, calling `toRaw` helped me.

```js
import { toRaw } from 'vue';
```

```js
this.map = new google.maps.Map(element, options);

let rawMap = toRaw(this.map);
    
const featureLayer = rawMap.getFeatureLayer(
    google.maps.FeatureType.POSTAL_CODE
)
```